# php-Codeigniter:route certain url to specific one

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, routes

I want to accelerate the static resources such as js,css,images to CDN.
Because the static and dynamic resources must be seperated I need to make `domain.com/src/....`to `src.domain.com/...`.

The `src` folder and the application folder of CodeIgniter are under same directory, updating  all the link of the static source will cost too much time.

Eg: I want to make `domain.com/src/images/1.jpg` alias to `src.domain.com/images/1.jpg`

The `src.domain.com` is accelerated by CDN and other url such as `domain.com/controller1`, `domain.com/controller2` needn't alias to `src.domain.com/controller1`, `src.domain.com/controller2`

I read the manual about route of codeigniter but I didn't get it.

Here is the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^src\/
  RewriteRule ^src\/(.*)$ http\:\/\/src1\.domain\.com\/$1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Create a `.htaccess` file and upload to `/` of your web-directory (codeigniter directory).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^src\/
RewriteRule ^src\/(.*)$ http\:\/\/src\.domain\.com\/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect `http://domain.com/src/images/1.jpg` to `http://src.domain.com/images/1.jpg`

similarly, `http://domain.com/src/videos/v1.mp4` to `http://src.domain.com/videos/v1.mp4`

However, please note that this is just a temporary solution!
In order to get the max out of your CDN, you need manually point images to your CDN in order to save one HTTP for every image.

Comment: Should I add this to .htaccess or httpd.conf?

Comment: should be added to .htaccess file

Comment: Create a `.htaccess` file and upload to `/` of your web-directory (codeigniter directory).

Comment: try entering `domain.com/src/` add `/` at the end, because in `RewriteCond` its `/` at the end of pattern `src`.